# AngularJS - Breaking controllers for running functions on page loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating my first app using Angular so hope this question is clear.

On my webpage, I have a `ul` that I'll be populating with JSON data. I've creating a service that successfully gets the JSON from an API using the `$http` service.

My question now is, I want to run a method that gets this data each time my home page loads (as that's where the `ul` is).

So in my controller, after declaring that method, I'm simply calling it:

```
self.checkJSON = function() {
   jsonService.getResults();
}

this.checkJSON();
```

What I'd like to know is:

1 - Is the best way to call that function each time page loads or is there a way to assign to say a `div` that contains the `ul` so that whenever the div is shown it runs that method.

2 - I guess based on question 1, if what i already have above is correct, in terms of calling the function, should there be a controller for each page? Otherwise if i have one controller, then on other pages this function is also going to get called.
(And i presume its ok to have multiple controllers on 1 page?)

Any advice appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Yes doing it in controller is the proper way. You always think of controller and data models first... then let angular create the DOM and behaviors based on those data models. Controller for each page/feature is appropriate. Then when you see the need for sharing data or methods you do that through services

Comment: I think its all clicked into place. Thanks charlietfl!